# how to find Name* section

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I use the same code for Email or Website and it works (it's at the end of the site). But I cant find Name. I can't understand what could be the reason.

```
url='http://blog.iese.edu/expatriatus/2011/06/09/social-media-help-to-ease- 
%E2%80%9Cexpat-blues%E2%80%9D/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
text=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Name')]")
```

Comment: That URL results in a 404.

Comment: sry
http://blog.iese.edu/expatriatus/2011/06/09/social-media-help-to-ease-%E2%80%9Cexpat-blues%E2%80%9D/